# How to assert UITextfield UITests

Tags: ios, coded-ui-tests

```
XCUIElement *accountTextField = [[element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeTextField] elementBoundByIndex:0];
XCUIElement *passwordTextField = [[element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeTextField] elementBoundByIndex:1];

[accountTextField tap];
[accountTextField typeText:@"123"];
[passwordTextField tap];
[passwordTextField typeText:@"123"];
[element tap];
XCTAssertTrue(accountTextField.exists, @"Text accountTextField doesn't exist");
XCTAssertTrue(passwordTextField.exists, @"Text passwordTextField doesn't exist");

XCTAssertEqual([accountTextField.value stringValue], @"test", @"wrong account");
```

error message:

> ([accountTextField.value stringValue] equal to (@"test")) failed:throwing "-[NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecongnized selector sent to instance 0xa000000003332313

Comment: XCTAssertEqual([accountTextField.value stringValue], @"test", "account wrong");

Comment: Please post (in your question) your code as actual text, not as an image. Also post the full error as text, not as an image.

Comment: thanks , please see my questions again.

Comment: What kind of test suite are you using? The [tag:coded-ui-tests] tag is for Microsoft's Visual Studio but I have never seen any Coded UI test with all those square brackets (the `[` and `]`) used as in your code. If you add the correct tags to your question and remove the incorrect ones you may get help quicker.